# how to easily work out the 'valid' region for np.convolve

Tags: python, numpy

Silly question - but is there a numpy function that returns the 'shape' of the convolve function when it is working in 'valid' mode.

Basically I have an issue working out which 'x' values match which y ones - and comparing it with the original data?

ie

```
import numpy as np

x= np.arange(0,1000)
y=np.random.rand(1000)
print np.shape(x)
print np.shape(y)

window = (np.ones(10))
ydash= np.convolve(y, window, "valid")

print np.shape(ydash)
#xdash = ?
```

How do i find out in general which elements of ydash correspond to elements in x.  (i guess i can work it out - but it seems like there should be a function that does this....

Comment: The docstring for `convolve` explains the length of the result for the "valid" mode.  Is it not clear?

Comment: I guess i should have made the word "easy" more clear.  I guess I don't want to have to delve into what convolve does if i can help it - time pressures!.  Essentially it is like np.max, and np.argmax.  Argmax tells you where max came from.  I want something that tells me what has happened to y - in terms of which elements are now dropped, and how it should line up with 'x'.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `y.shape - window.shape + 1`